# Append data dynamically to existing JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following JSON structure,

```
#JSON 1
     {
            "objects": 
             [
                {
                    "type": "chocolate",
                    "id": "c1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "sweet",
                    "id": "s1"
                }
            ]
      }
```

How do I append data dynamically using Javascript? Something like this:

```
#JSON 2
         [
           {
            "data": {      
                    "type": "chocolate",
                    "id": "c1"
                }
            },
            {
            "data": {
                    "type": "sweet",
                    "id": "s1"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I've used the fetch API to read the file as it is a huge JSON file.
and I do not want to hardcode type and id. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: you'll need to parse the JSON string to a javascript object first, then stringify the result to get back to JSON

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes with the fetch API, the JSON is already parsed to js object. But how do I append the "data: "        , see #JSON2

Comment: oh, so, you're not dealing with JSON, you're dealing with a javascript object - that's easy

Comment: lets say your object is in a variable called `result` ...then it's just `result.objects = result.objects.map(data => ({data}))`

Comment: @Jaromanda X, my apologies. I'm referring to JSON. I'm really confused with the terms as I just started learning JS. I read online JS object looks something like this var a = "car";  Am I right?

Comment: JSON is a data interchange format - and is a string .. but what you have from fetch API, if you use `response.json()` is a JS object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously you're getting this result from fetch, but for the purposes of demonstrating what you need to do I'm initialising it inline

```js
let result = { 
    "type": "test",
    "id": "123",
    "objects": 
    [
        {
            "type": "chocolate",
            "id": "c1"
        },
        {
            "type": "sweet",
            "id": "s1"
        }
    ]
};
let finalResult = result.objects.map(data => ({data}));
console.log(finalResult);
```

You mention using fetch - it'd be simply like

```
fetch(url)
.then(result => result.json())
.then(result => result.objects.map(data => ({data})))
.then(finalResult => {
    // here the result is in the format you want
    console.log(finalResult);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this line? `result => result.objects.map(data => ({data})` Is it trying to append data?

Comment: `function (result) {
  return result.objects.map(function (data) {
    return { data: data };
  });
};` in old javascript

Comment: nope, as I can't see what you've done now - probably something wrong